# What is a short way to import external React components?

Tags: docusaurus

In the `docs` directory (docusaurus project) I create `markdown` files and these MD files contain imports from external react project (it's a local project placed in other directory).

Everything works fine, but one tiny thing. Now I import files like this:

```js
import Component from '../../../react-project/src/components/Component';
```

I don't know how to shorten the path. I'd like to write something like this:

```js
import Component from '@components/Component';
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have your separate components within a git repository, you can reference that repository as an imported module.

`npm install git+https://github.com/yourUser/yourRepositoryName`

`import {Component} from yourRepositoryName`